# If I have two physically equivalent but logically different types of data, then how many hashes should I use to store them?

Tags: coding-style

Say I have two set of items, which are similar except for their logical purpose in the program. Is it better programming practice to assign two hashes to them, or should I use only one hash for the purpose?

Comment: Similar (lists and sets, both collections) or identical (two lists of strings, one user names and the other passwords)? Normally I would separate different logical data, but more context here would be helpful.

Comment: Identical would be the word, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store them in the same hash table, you run the (perhaps small or non-existent) risk of overwriting one with another. Say for example you are storing first names and last names (both strings). There could conceivably be one person with first name "Jones" and another with last name "Jones".

If the above is not possible there's no technical reason why you could not use a single hash table. Items that hash to the same value will be stored in the same bucket along with other items with different hash values that map to the same bucket, but as long as you check for actual equality after hash collision, you're okay.

That being said, I would still prefer to separate logical items into their own hash tables without a very strong reason to combine them.

- The code dealing with them will probably be easier to write and maintain.
- It will be easier to debug issues.
- Smaller hash tables will likely have fewer items per bucket and improve performance slightly.

Answer (score 0):

If the set of items are same, the hashes should be same as well.

It is like saying you can use a wrench to tighten a bolt or break open a window, hence it should behave like 2 different objects, which isn't true, because it is your way of use that is differentiating, not the object itself.